# How to bring the build process to an end when one of the target uses java ant with fork set to true

Tags: java, tomcat, ant, parallel-processing, build.xml

I have three targets of which one is using java as shown below

// Target that has java task

```
<java classname="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" fork="true" classpathref="tomcat.class.path">
            <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${build.tomcat.dir}" />
            <arg line="start" />
        </java>
```

My main target depends on the above target which has this java ant. The problem is everything works fine... this java ant starts my tomcat server and the control is not moved to the next target. Build.xml will be in running state.

How do I make the control move to the next targer once the target with java ant is done with the execution.

I have used parallel with daemons element and it worked fine... started the server and the control moved the next target. But the problem here is once I see a message in the console that server is up and when I try to access tomcat, it is up and running. Once the entire build is done and Build Successful message is displayed then again if I try to access tomcat, I do not see it up and running.

Any help please...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting spawn = "true"

```
<java classname="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" fork="true" spawn="true" classpathref="tomcat.class.path">
   <jvmarg value="-Dcatalina.home=${build.tomcat.dir}" />
   <arg line="start" />
</java>
```

Comment: Thank You. It works... but the server is starting very quickly i.e., in a second without showing any log statements. How is this done in the background?

Comment: It spawns another process in the background which is not observed by ant , therefore "outlives" ant. Once you fire this thing up you can't close it with ant.

Comment: I am able to stop the server using another ant target and then performing few activities (other targets) and then starting the tomcat server. Will there be any performance related issues using spawn?